# Implementing Iterable by returning an Iterator over a sub-type

Tags: java, generics, iterable

In the following code:

```
public class Bar { ... }

public class Foo extends Bar { ... }

public class BarIterable implements Iterable<Bar> {

    List<Foo> foos = ...

    @Override
    public Iterator<Bar> iterator() {
        return foos.iterator();  // Error: Type mismatch ...
    }
}
```

I get an error at the indicated position since `foos.iterator()` returns an `Iterable<Foo>` rather than an `Iterable<Bar>`. Unfortunately, a simple cast won't work:

```
return (Iterator<Bar>) foos.iterator();  // Error: Cannot cast ...
```

Java also doesn't allow me to change the definition of `BarIterable` to

```
public class BarIterable implements Iterable<? extends Bar> { ...   // Error: A supertype may not specify any wildcard
```

What's a good way to resolve this problem that does **not** involve implementing `Iterable<Foo>` instead (the Iterable-implementation comes from another interface that doesn't know about Foo)?

Do I have to write myself a wrapper Iterator-class that "unpacks" each value?

Comment: I'm not certain, but it looks like you are implementing inheritance and this line `public class BarIterable implements Iterable<Bar>` should instead be `public class BarIterable extends Iterable<Bar>`, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @AlvinBunk `Iterable` is an interface, so I definitely need to use `implements`, not `extends`.

Comment: How do you get `foos`?

Comment: Ok, can you post more of your code so I can try it out in Eclipse?

Comment: Can't you change your `foos` to `List<Bar> foos`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's just an example, but let's say foos is some ArrayList I populate inside BarIterable. I could just make it a List<Bar> instead, but then I'd have to use casts everytime I want to use the list somewhere else to access Foos...

Comment: @assylias While that would work for this example, it brings other issues with it and I'm more interested in how to handle this problem in general...

Comment: I would argue that this is a defect with the `Iterable` interface. Since `Iterator` is a producer, we should always use `Iterator<? extends X>`, and never `Iterator<X>`, and thus the `.iterator()` method of `Iterable<T>` should return `Iterator<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar`, you could just cast the `List`.

```
return ((List<Bar>)(List<? extends Bar>) foos).iterator();
```

and suppress the warnings.

*Edit by Markus A.:*

Or, you can cast the iterator directly using the intermediate-cast-trick:

```
return (Iterator<Bar>)(Iterator<? extends Bar>) foos.iterator();
```

*End edit*

---

With Java 8, you can stream over the elements and construct a new `List` of type `Bar`.

```
@Override
public Iterator<Bar> iterator() {
    return foos.stream().<Bar>map((foo) -> foo /* considered a Bar */).collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator();  
}
```

but you're doing a lot of intermediate operations just to view the `List` from a super type's point of view.

Comment: THERE we go! Awesome! I was trying the list-cast, but it didn't let me do it, but I didn't know about the trick to indirect the cast via an intermediate cast using `? extends`. Nice! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can cast the iterator directly that way!